# What exactly is effective interaction with regards to Feynman diagrams?

Tags: potential, feynman-diagrams, many-body, correlation-functions, 1pi-effective-action

What does it actually mean to calculate to calculate the effective interaction using Feynman diagrams? To be concrete, let us consider the example of [random phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_phase_approximation) (RPA) calculation of the screening effect of Fermi gas, i.e., we have the usual free Hamiltonian $H_k = \sum_k \epsilon_k c^*_{k\sigma} c_{k\sigma}$ and the usual Coulomb interaction
$$
H_I=\frac{1}{2}\sum V_q c_{k'+q ,\sigma'}^*c_{k-q,\sigma}^*c_{k\sigma} c_{k'\sigma'}
$$
Where the spins run over $N=2s+1$ components and the original interaction is rescaled $V_q = \mathcal{V}_q/N$, and $V(q=0)$ is well-defined by some regularization, e.g., $1/q^2 \mapsto 1/(q^2+0^+)$. Then it is usually said that the effective interaction is computed via the following Feynman diagrams
[image]

**Question**. For quick understanding, the Feynman diagrams are very useful, but if I were to actually sit down and calculate, it's often difficult to keep track of all the signs and $i$ and so forth just by looking at the diagrams, so what I would prefer is a well-defined definition. For example, in imaginary time, it could be something like
$$
\frac{\langle \mathcal{T}c^*(4)c^*(3)c(2)c(1) S(\beta)\rangle}{\langle S(\beta)\rangle} = \langle  \mathcal{T}c^*(4)c^*(3)c(2)c(1)\rangle V_\text{eff}(4,3,2,1)
$$
where $4=(k_4,\sigma_4,\tau_4)$ and similarly for $3,2,1$ and $S(\beta)$ is the usual imaginary-time $S$-matrix for the interaction $H_I$, i.e.,
$$
S(\beta) = \mathcal{T}\exp\left( -\int_0^\beta H_I(\tau)d\tau\right)
$$
Indeed, since Feynman diagrams are just visual tools to keep track of the decomposition in Wick's theorem, it seems reasonable to assume that the effective interaction is somehow extracted from well-defined correlation functions. However, I haven't quite seen any textbook defining it this way.

**EDIT**. In case anyone's interested, Negele and Orland's *Quantum Many-particle systems* does a pretty good job of explaining this with the Legendre transform of generating functions in Chapter 2.4.